# Combine if blocks with repetitive code

Tags: coding, logic

I have this piece of code

```
if (!expr1) {
    codeblock1;
} elseif (expr2) {
    codeblock2;

    codeblock1;
}
```

It is pissing the hell out of me because I am trying to refactor it in such a way that there is no repetitive code, but I keep getting different results.

```
if (!expr1 || expr2) {
    if (expr2) {
        codeblock2;
    }

    codeblock1;
}
```

What is the logical difference between these two examples?

Comment: rather blatant duplicate of [Avoid Code Repetition in Condition Statements](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/254235/avoid-code-repetition-in-condition-statements)

Comment: When expr1=false and expr2=true, your first code listing will only execute codeblock1 due to the `elseif`. The second code listing will execute codeblock2 and codeblock1 instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In snippet 1 you are explicitly stating that you don't want `codeblock2` to be run if `expr1` is false.

In snippet 2 you are stating that you DO want `codeblock2` to be run, even if `expr1` is false, as long as `expr2` is true.

Also, assuming that `codeblock1` and `codeblock2` are a series of lines of code (more that just one line), you can extract them to methods. That way you could do:

```
if (!expr1) {
    codeblock1(); // calling a method
} elseif (expr2) {
    codeblock2(); // calling a method
    codeblock1(); // calling a method
}
```

... which is not cosidered code repetition.

Answer (score 5):

In this specific case, a nice way to refactor your code would be to make the conditions clearer. (Make sure to put the following  code into a function)

```
if (expr1 and !expr2)
    return;
if (expr1 and expr2)
    codeblock2();
codeblock1();
```

If you read the code line by line, you see:

- If expr1 is true, and expr2 is false, don't do anything, leave the function
- If expr1 is true and expr2 is true, run codeblock2
- run codeblock1

It makes it very clear what conditions you are actually checking for, and what happens when that specific condition is met.